# bootstrap 4 and tab issue

Tags: php, bootstrap-4, tabs

I tried this but I dont understand why it's doesn't work with bootstrap 4. The tab appear but it's impossible to see the content.

Thank you

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="myTab">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <?php echo '<a href="' . substr(OSCOM::link( '/suppliers.php', osc_get_all_get_params(), 'AUTO'), strlen($base_url)) . '#tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link active">' . TAB_GENERAL . '</a>'; ?></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <?php echo '<a href="' . substr(OSCOM::link( 'admin/suppliers.php', osc_get_all_get_params(), 'AUTO'), strlen($base_url)) . '#tab2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link">' . TAB_SUPPLIERS_NOTE; ?></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <?php echo '<a href="' . substr(OSCOM::link( 'ClicShoppingAdmin/suppliers.php', osc_get_all_get_params(), 'AUTO'), strlen($base_url)) . '#tab3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link">' . TAB_VISUEL; ?></a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
        test1
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
        test2
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
        test3
    </div>
</div>
```

If you look this it work perfectly : https://codepen.io/jek/pen/BoWNRy
My #tab2 and id="tab2" seems correct

I tried also with a direct url like this, but it doesn't work.

```
   <a class="nav-link" href="http://test.com/boutique/admin/suppliers.php#tab2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo TAB_SUPPLIERS_NOTE; ?></a>
```

Comment: Did you activate the JavaScript which triggers the tabs on a link click? See http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navs/#javascript-behavior.

Comment: I found a solution: substr(OSCOM::link( 'ClicShoppingAdmin/suppliers.php', osc_get_all_get_params(), 'AUTO'), strlen($base_url)) and I remove subtr and osc_get_all_get_params() and it works. But If a valid a page and I want to stay on the same tab, now it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if this is what you wanted. But to get the test1, test2, test3 as results I think you have to refer the id of **tab-content** elements in **href** tags of **nav-items**

I just tried to modify your code and it looked like this (without php)

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="myTab">
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link"  href="#tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="tab1">TAB_GENERAL </a> 
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#tab2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="tab1">TAB_SUPPLIERS_NOTE</a> 
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
 <a class="nav-link" href="#tab3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="tab1">TAB_VISUEL</a> 
</li>
```

```
<div class="tab-content">
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab1">
    test1
</div>
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
    test2
</div>
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
    test3
</div>
```

If you want to display a website content inside the **nav-tab**  you may use an iframe

Cheerz